# Alternative to Running Axios in Computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am working on a high school project involving chemical data. I need to get a response from this URL and reference it in another function. When I try to use descriptionURL in my mounted function, I get an error saying it is undefined. Any help not involving 3rd party additions would be appreciated.

Note: the properties.CID is coming from a request from the mounted function.

```js
computed: {
    description() {
      var descriptionURL = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/cid/" + this.properties.CID + "/description/json"
      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(descriptionURL);
      axios
        .get(this.descriptionURL)
        //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        .then(response => {this.descriptionText = response.data})
          //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        .catch(function (error) {
          //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(error);

        })
        return descriptionURL
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: can you provide one demo `this.properties.CID` value

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that I find puzzling in your snippet.

To begin with, there is a variable called *descriptionURL* that is defined within the scope of the *description()* computed property. However, axios is sending a request to *this.descriptionURL*, which would be a variable defined at the component level, hence not the *descriptionURL* variable mentioned before. Is that intentional?

Also, your computed property returns *descriptionURL*, which might not be the content that you want to use.

Moreover, [Computed properties should not have side effects](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.html), which yours seems to do (altering the property *descriptionText* ). I would recommend using a method instead of a computed property.

If you really intended your computed property to return *descriptionURL*, then you can access this value by calling *this.description* (as opposed to *this.descriptionURL*) in *mounted()*.

Finally, since the API call needs some time to get a response, it is unlikely that wou will be able to use its result within mounted().

In case you are looking for alternatives, here is how I would implement this feature with my current understanding of the situation:

```js
data(){
  return{
    descriptionText: null,
  }
},
method: {
  get_description() {
    var descriptionURL = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/cid/" + this.properties.CID + "/description/json"
    axios.get(descriptionURL)
    .then(response => { this.descriptionText = response.data })
    .catch((error) => { console.error(error) })
  },
  other_method_using_description(){

    // Check if descriptionText actually contains a description
    if(!this.descriptionText) {
      console.error('descriptionText is still null')
      return
    }

    // use this.descriptionText
  }
}
```

In this example, get_description is a method used to populate the descriptionText property with the response from the HTTP request.

You can then use this property in other functions, assuming it has received data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `.get(descriptionURL)` instead of `.get(this.descriptionURL)`, because `descriptionURL` is in `description()` scope and not on vue instance.